# Is there a way to subtract two columns containing Quarters and return the integer number of Quarters between them?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am conducting a cohort analysis based on the ending quarter of a subscription term (i.e. Cohorts are organized by the expiration quarter of your first contract).

I am trying to create the periods for my cohort analysis by subtracting the clients Cohort Quarter from their most recent Expiration Quarter. In other words, I want to know how many quarters have elapsed from their first expiration quarter to their most recent expiration quarter.

I tried straight subtraction

```
df_cohort = all_time.groupby(['Cohort', 'End Quarter']).agg({'Account Name':'nunique'}) \
              .reset_index(drop=False)
df_cohort['period_number'] = (df_cohort['End Quarter'] - df_cohort.Cohort)
df_cohort
```

Which results in a QuarterEnd value containing the answer I am looking for (the integer number of Quarters difference).

```
    Cohort  End Quarter Account Name    period_number
0   2015Q1  2015Q1        13    <0 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>
1   2015Q1  2015Q3         1    <2 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>
2   2015Q1  2018Q4         1    <15 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>
3   2015Q1  2019Q2         1    <17 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>
4   2015Q1  2019Q3         1    <18 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>
5   2015Q1  2020Q1         3    <20 * QuarterEnds: startingMonth=12>
```

Whereas what I really want is this:

```
    Cohort  End Quarter Account Name    period_number
0   2015Q1  2015Q1         13              0
1   2015Q1  2015Q3         1               2
2   2015Q1  2018Q4         1               15
3   2015Q1  2019Q2         1               17
4   2015Q1  2019Q3         1               18
5   2015Q1  2020Q1         3               20
```

All attempts I have made to get a simple integer from that calculation have failed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant way to do this, but you skip having to define dates ans so on. I made a df for just the problem:

```
dfq = pd.read_csv(r"C:/users/k_sego/quarter.csv",sep=";")
print(dfq)
```

which looks like this

```
   Cohort EndQuarter
0  2015Q1     2015Q1
1  2015Q1     2015Q3
2  2015Q1     2018Q4
3  2015Q1     2019Q2
4  2015Q1     2019Q3
5  2015Q1     2020Q1
```

I extract the quarters from each date column into new column nd keep track of where they come from, as well as the year. Remember to convert to numeric.

```
dfq['CohortQ'] = dfq.Cohort.str.slice(5,6)
dfq['EndQuarterQ'] = dfq.EndQuarter.str.slice(5,6)
dfq['CohortYear'] = dfq.Cohort.str.slice(0,4)
dfq['EndQuarterYear'] = dfq.EndQuarter.str.slice(0,4)
cols = dfq.columns.drop(['Cohort','EndQuarter'])

dfq[cols] = dfq[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
```

Now, the difference between years times 4 is the number of quarter, but to this you need to add the difference between the quarters at which the years were at.

```
dfq['CountQuarters'] = (dfq['EndQuarterYear']-dfq['CohortYear'])*4 +(dfq['EndQuarterQ']-dfq['CohortQ'])
```

which gives

```
   Cohort EndQuarter  CohortQ  EndQuarterQ  CohortYear  EndQuarterYear  \
0  2015Q1     2015Q1        1            1        2015            2015   
1  2015Q1     2015Q3        1            3        2015            2015   
2  2015Q1     2018Q4        1            4        2015            2018   
3  2015Q1     2019Q2        1            2        2015            2019   
4  2015Q1     2019Q3        1            3        2015            2019   
5  2015Q1     2020Q1        1            1        2015            2020   

   CountQuarters  
0              0  
1              2  
2             15  
3             17  
4             18  
5             20
```

Comment: Thank you! Elegant or inelegant, this did the trick.

Comment: Glad you had some use for it.

Comment: Accept (check) and tick the answer so it doesn't longer appear as an open one.